# Ubuntu 14.04LTS How to generate an a Windows Azure Compatible .cer key

Tags: 14.04, ssl, openssl, certificates

How can I generate a **.cer** public key certificate file using ubuntu so that I can upload it onto Azure VPN management portal since it doesn't allow any other formats?

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a crt with pem encoding and rename it to cer.  (short question = short answer) If you give some more info, I can too.